# AWS Simple Email Service not filtering IP addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, console, amazon-ses

When using Amazon SES and defining IP Address Filters on the email server, users who are not part of the IP address filters can still send emails through Amazon SES.

I am looking to know if this is expected behaviour or if there is something that I need to do in order to get IP filtering working on Amazon SES in order to protect the email server from being compromised.

I have looked into using the IP Address Filters on the Amazon SES documentation but nothing seems to be working. I created a block list and a allow list.

I created a block list and a allow list for an environment that should not be able to access the server yet users can still send emails from Amazon SES if they know the trusted email address.

Comment: Unless you are referring to something entirely different, [SES IP Address Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-ip-filters.html) block *receiving inbound* mail -- not sending.  Sending and receiving are completely unrelated feature capabilities in SES.  *"...users can still send emails from Amazon SES if they know the trusted email address."* It's not clear what this means.  You can't send email through SES without credentials.  It sounds like you need to clarify your uses of words like "send" and "from."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, it seems that I was just unsure of what the IP filters were for Amazon SES. I thought the filtering was to prevent users from being able to send emails to others and not being able to block mail being received from an IP address. That being said, I did create a single IP filter of `0.0.0.0/0` (of type block) and I was still able to receive mail. Shouldn't this of not worked? Any thoughts on this?